# Passing parameters to a patch function in php

Tags: php, prepared-statement

I've just begun developing code in php, and currently I'm developing a small API for a faculty at my university.

I'm using prepared statements to interact with a MySQL database, but in this function the parameters do not get passed to the function.

```
function patch_admin() {

    global $db,$file, $settings;
    $payload = get_json();

    if($payload[password_crypt] != NULL)
    {
        metamessage(lang('please_use_password_function'));
        return HTTP_BAD_REQUEST;
    }

    if($payload[admin_id] != NULL)
    {
        foreach($payload as $key => $value) {
            if($key == "admin_id") { continue; }

            $querystr="UPDATE " .table('admin'). " SET :key=:value WHERE admin_id=:admin_id";
            $params = [ ':key' => $key, ':value' => $value, ':admin_id' => $payload[admin_id]];
            $query = $db->prepare($querystr);
            $query->execute($params);
       }
   }

   return HTTP_BAD_REQUEST;
}
```

The query and the parameters look like this:

```
UPDATE or_admin 
SET :key = :value 
WHERE admin_id=:admin_id

Array
(
    [:key] => fname
    [:value] => Bernharddiener
    [:admin_id] => 1626704194
)
```

Am I missing something obvious here?

When I replace the :key with the field names, I'm able to patch the database, but I want to get the column names from the JSON I send.

Best regards,
Til

Comment: PDO can't replace table and column names like this, only column values. You need to use PHP variables for this and sanitise it yourself using a whitelist.

Answer (score 0):

You should check and set params the same way you do with the table name

Ex :

```
    $querystr="UPDATE " .table('admin'). " SET `".mysql_real_escape_string($key)."` =:value WHERE admin_id=:admin_id";
    $params = [ ':value' => $value, ':admin_id' => $payload[admin_id]];
```

Comment: Thanks, you put me in the right diroction. While it seems that mysql_real_escape_string is no longer supported (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) , this line worked for me: $querystr="UPDATE " .table('admin'). " SET ".$key." =:value WHERE admin_id=:admin_id";

Comment: if you're sure about what's in $key, no need to escape it indeed :)